# Derivation of the finite population correction factor?

Tags: statistics, covariance

How can you prove that the finite population correction factor when applied to the sample mean should be

[image]

I believe that you start off by considering the cases where the random variables $x_i$ in the sample are not independent, so that the additivity of variance must then include a covariance term. However, where do you go from there?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6577359

Comment: The derivation is given on an answer to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/explanation-of-finite-population-correction-factor